# Bypass ngrok visitor warning without the ability to set custom headers

Tags: ngrok

I'm currently trying to connect an external service to an API on my laptop via Ngrok. I've set the Ngrok link, but when my external service calls the URL, it gets a HTML response instead of calling the API on my laptop.

I noticed that when I open my Ngrok URL I see the following warning page:

[image]

The page explains that I can remove the warning by setting a header, but that isn't possible in my current case. The option of paying 20 euro's per month for each developer also isn't an option I currently want to explore.

Sharing a much older AuthKey with a colleague of mine by passed the error, but this workaround won't allow you both to setup different tunnels at the same time.

I've also looked into alternatives such as Localtunnel as some answers on Stackoverflow recommended this, but that also has a similar error page.

Is it possible to work around this error page if you can't set any headers with Ngrok?

Answer (score 3):

I've been in contact with Ngrok support and they have told me that this message is tied to authtokens of new accounts. Authtokens tied to old accounts  work around this warning because these accounts are different from the new accounts.

The warning page has been added to protect users from malicious URL's and according to support can only be removed via the work around listed on the page.

As a possible extra workaround you can share any old account tokens between developers by replacing the authtoken in your ngrok folder with a token from an old account. This has one downside, you can't open multiple ngrok tunnels at the same time with a other user that uses your token.